# jquery function with parameters not working

Tags: jquery

I have made a function with parameters but it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
 function hideQuestion( _hideQuestion, _showQuestion){
   $('#_showQuestion').removeClass('hideOnInit');
   $('#_hideQuestion').addClass('hideOnInit');
   }
```

If I use the function like this

```
<a id='_b_Startpage2' href=\"#Question_01_01\" onclick='hideQuestion(question1, question2);' data-role='button'></a>
```

...nothing happens.

How can can I fix it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use the function `parameter` variables and you are using `constant string` instead. Also pass the `ids` from `onclick` as a stirng constant.

```
function hideQuestion( _hideQuestion, _showQuestion){
   $('#' + _showQuestion).removeClass('hideOnInit');
   $('#' + _hideQuestion).addClass('hideOnInit');
}
```

Change

```
<a id='_b_Startpage2' href=\"#Question_01_01\" onclick='hideQuestion(question1, question2);' data-role='button'></a>
```

To

```
<a id='_b_Startpage2' href=\"#Question_01_01\" onclick='hideQuestion("question1", "question2");' data-role='button'></a>
```

In javascript strings could be enclosed in `single` or `double` quotes and could be combined as we did on `onclick`

```
 onclick='hideQuestion("question1", "question2");'
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a function and a parameter which is fine..but you have not used the parameter in your function...
try this.

```
function hideQuestion( _hideQuestion, _showQuestion){
   $('#'+_showQuestion).removeClass('hideOnInit');  //using the set variable here...
   $('#'+_hideQuestion).addClass('hideOnInit');
```

}

and your html , yo need to pass the parameter.. here i am sending a string

```
<a id='_b_Startpage2' href=\"#Question_01_01\" onclick='hideQuestion("question1", "question2");' data-role='button'></a>  // sending thevariable to the functin as parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

Adil's solution should work. Your issue is that with your code you are searching for the variables `"#_showQuestion"` and `"#_hideQuestion"` which you do not declare or are interested in finding